# Python - Store strings from text file into a variable

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm wanting a script that will store the first word from each line from an input file into a variable.

Current code only stores the last name.

```
def func(file): 
  global user 
  with open(file) as iFile: 
    for line in iFile: 
    string = line.split(',') 
    user = string[0]

func(sys.argv[1]) 
print user
```

The text file input is:

```
string1,string2,string3
string1,string2,string3
string1,string2,string3
```

I want the variable `user` to store the all of the string1's on each line from the text file.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect, you may want to correct that. Next, you are confusing `user` and `username` in your code. Last but not least, did you want a *list* of strings perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, corrected the 'user' and 'username'. Yes, a list would work. Not too sure though, hehe. New to this.

Comment: make user a list `user.append( string[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indenting issue.

This will fix it. I also changed your func, so that you no longer use a global but instead return a generator with the users from the list.

This is a better practise and more memory efficient.

```
def func(file): 
  with open(file) as iFile: 
    for line in iFile: 
        string = line.split(',') 
        yield string[0]

for user in func(sys.argv[1]) 
    print user
```

Answer (score 1):

i recommend this

```
def func(path):
    with open(path) as _file:
        return [s.split(',')[0] for s in _file]

user = func(sys.argv[1])
print user
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this :

```
user = []
def func(file): 
  with open(file) as iFile: 
    for line in iFile: 
      user.append(line.split(',')[0])

func(sys.argv[1]) 
print user
```

It stores in a list all "first string" of every line you will provide to the function. By the way the solution of Matt PsyK is totally more efficient!